# How to configure touchscreen to work with android OS pi?

Tags: touchscreen, android

I have a Raspberry pi 4 with 2GB and a touchscreen https://www.elecrow.com/7-inch-1024-600-hdmi-lcd-display-with-touch-screen.html

I installed this android 13 image https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/AOSP13/

Added to config.txt

```
hdmi_force_edid_audio=1
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=7
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=2
display_rotate=0
hdmi_cvt=1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
```

Having:

- dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d:

  - touch screen - stuck on boot with ANDROID letters
  - HDMI monitor - same
- dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d

  - touch screen - black screen
  - HDMI monitor - ok

How to configure this touchscreen to work with android pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing this android OS version https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/LineageOS20/

I removed `resolution.txt`

and I added this to `config.txt`

```
hdmi_cvt=1024 600 60 3 0 0 0
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
max_framebuffers=2
```

Comment: it's a typo pardon